# SQL SUM() function always returns 0

Tags: asp.net, sql, sum

I'm executing this statement on an ASP.NET platform with SQL Server

```
SELECT id, size, color, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN storeID IN ('E13','E15','E10') THEN stock ELSE 0 END) 
        + SUM(CASE WHEN storeID IN ('E13','E15','E10') THEN incoming ELSE 0 END) 
        - SUM(CASE WHEN storeID IN ('E13','E15','E10') THEN outgoing ELSE 0 END) 
    AS Total 
FROM stocks 
GROUP BY id, size, color
```

And this is the code I'm using to retrieve the obtained values

```
For Each rowStock In TableStocks.Rows
    Dim product As New ProductInfo
    With product
        .id = rowStock("id")
        .size = rowStock("size")
        .color = rowStock("color")
        .stock = rowStock("Total")
    End With
Next
```

`id`, `size` and `color` values are correct, but the result of the `SUM` function is always 0. If I run the query on the SQL Server management it works fine.

I've tried changing

```
.stock = rowStock(3)
```

instead of

```
.stock = rowStock("Total")
```

but I'm getting the same result. I can't figure what I'm missing.

Comment: What do the 3 SUMs return individually?

Comment: There seems cases return zero in given condition or the values are,check sum of all values in formula separately.

Comment: @gbn The first SUM returns the actual stock for each product. The second one, returns the number of units ordered to the producer. The last one returns the number of units shipped to the producer due to manufacturing defects

Comment: @Cpt.Awesome - that is obvious but it is **not** what *gbn* asked.

Comment: gbn (and all of us now) want to know the individual results of your sums. Any chance they are 10, 10 and 20?

Comment: @Cpt.Awesome: I meant "what values does each SUM return". The *meaning* of each SUM is irrelevant to the question...

Comment: The three SUMs return, in my first product, 5 - 1 - 0

Comment: @Cpt.Awesome: Then you'd get 6 obviously.  The problem lies in how you're consuming the multiple rows. SQL is not at fault. Do you need to DIM every loop?

Comment: @Cpt.Awesome - I would try replacing the entire `Total` statement with `3 AS Total` and see if you get a 3 out of it. If you don't, I would assume you are not calling the statement you think you are calling.

Comment: @gbn No, I don't need to Dim every loop. I've tried without that, but I get the same result. @Lieven I'll try the `3 Total` theory

Comment: Have you checked the get/set for the stock propery of the ProductInfo class? Or debugging with a watch on `rowStock("Total")`. This should give you a better idea of where the error is occurring.

Comment: Also, check your database session configuration.  If you try to SUM() on NULL values, the ANSI behavior is to return NULL which may get converted to 0 by the framework.  In SQL Server, the default behavior is to treat NULLs as 0, but if your application is setting session specific settings, it may have different behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my own question. I've saved my query into a stored procedure on the database and it works as I expected.

**EDIT**

I've found another solution without using stored procedures. I realized that before running the sql statement, it's converted to lower case. So I decided to use `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` in `storeID` field, just to give it a try. It worked!

The final SQL query is

```
SELECT id, size, color,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN storeID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
    IN ('E13','E15','E10') THEN stock + incoming - outgoing ELSE 0 END)  
  AS Total 
FROM stocks 
GROUP BY id, size, color
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see is the extra comma after "total," which indicates another column name is expected in the query before the "from" keyword and choking...

Other than that, I would alter your query to ...

```
SELECT
      id, size, color, sum( stock + incoming - outgoing ) as Total
   FROM
     stocks 
   where
      storeID IN ('E13','E15','E10')
   GROUP BY 
      id, size, color
```

Comment: Your alternative query returns considerably different results. The original query returns rows even if storeID is not in IN list. *If* you want to simplify the query Total can be computer e.g. with `SUM(CASE WHEN storeID IN ('E13','E15','E10') THEN stock + incoming - outgoing ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @AndreLoker, you are correct. however, it looked like they were looking for inventory for a few specific stores.  If I had a business with large inventory (say 1000's of items), and the locations I was concerned with only had say 200, I wouldn't want a list of bloat I would never look at.

Comment: without knowing the exact requirements, it's difficult to say which way to go. At least we have shown multiple ways to simplify the query so the original author may pick what suits him best. That doesn't solve his original issue, though.

Comment: @AndreLoker I simplified the sql query as you suggested. The problem still remains, but the code is more readable now. Thanks!

Comment: @Cpt.Awesome, have you done as others suggested and tried to "Step-through" this in your debugger.. I would start IMMEDIATELY AT the execution of your query, see if any SQL errors encountered and not returning a result set.  Then, within your For EACH, make sure the get/set code for the property is getting a value.  Pre-check the value in your debugger via a "watch" window expression of your data column you are about to pass into the function.  Sometimes doing a "SUM()" will return a decimal or double and if you are expecting INT, that MAY make it choke on you.

Comment: @DRapp the query returns a result set filled with correct values for `id`, `size` and `color`. But the `Total` field has a 0 in all the returned rows. Casting SUM() as INT doesn't resolve the issue. No SQL errors are encountered

Comment: @Cpt.Awesome, then I would just for grins, return ALL records WITHOUT using the sum() and GROUP BY clause, but return each individual column of stock, incoming, outgoing for each record and see what their values actually ARE.  Or.. is it COMPLETE coincidence that the net sum() actually IS zero.. stranger things have happened like generating random numbers of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5... :)